# Is there any way to return the Pose Position of armatures to Rest Position?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

I've moved some fingers in the pose mode, but I can't reset the armatures back to the rest position. All the results I searched on Google are "set the rest position to the current position" but I want the opposite instead!

I tried to select all the bones (including the hidden bones) to clear transform (Alt G+R+S) but it didn't work.
I right-clicked and "clear user transform" and it didn't work as well.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much! :)

My file:  https://we.tl/t-fVmL4wMBwu

The fingers after I apply clear transform:
[image: The fingers after I]

What I want the fingers to look like:
[image]

Comment: If you can share your project we can review the problem. But from what I see in the screenshoots, there are keyframes in the timeline, maybe that's the problem, delete all keyframes and maybe the problem will be solved.

Comment: I try to delete the keyframes but it seems no different. I just upload the file, please take a look. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to how to make the armature rest postion: delete all bone constraints.

The bone constraints are the reason that the armature, with cleared transforms on all bones, is not in the rest position.  One example of this would be MCH-upper_arm_ik_target.L , which has a copy location constraint targeting hand_ik.L -- but the rest position of hand_ik.L is not the same rest position as MCH-upper_arm_ik_target.L , so that is one (of perhaps multiple, I don't know) ways in which the untransformed position of the bones is different than the true rest position of the bones.

How did this happen?  Probably, you transformed one of those bones in edit mode.  Possibly, you created the constraint.

This looks like a rigify armature.  How can you avoid this happening when using a rigify armature?  Rigify rigs are designed in a way that any edits to the armature need to happen on the **meta-rig**, after which the main rig can be re-generated.  Rigify armatures are not necessarily designed to be edited directly.  You *can* edit them, but you have to know what you're doing, and even then, it's not really recommended, because those edits won't remain after you re-generate the rig from the metarig.